# Replacing one div with another with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="calculateButton" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/btn_calculate.gif")%>" />
</div>
<div id="calculateInProgress" style="text-align: left;">
    <br />
    Calculating...<img height='15px' src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/CreatingReport.gif")%>" />
</div>
```

So I have these two div's above. Basically what happens right now is that a user clicks the calculate button, and the div undernath of it appears, which is basically an animated gif that shows the user it's calculating. We INSTEAD want the gif to take the place of the button, and then when it's done, bring the button back. Here is the code we use now to do you EXTRA div, NOT the way we want it:

```
$('#calculateInProgress').show();
$('#calculateInProgress').hide();
```

Call show when they click it, it performs some operations, and when they complete it automatically calls hide.

How can I change this to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .html() method to replace contents with gif, and then back again

Comment: This should work, since you know what you'd like to have shown (the html defining the calculateInProgress vs the html defining the calculateButton) and you can replace the html whenever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Before calculation
$('#calculateButton').hide();
$('#calculateInProgress').show();

// In the Ajax callback
$('#calculateButton').show();
$('#calculateInProgress').hide();
```

Comment: This won't replace it. Just hide it. But you will still be able to see that the InProgress div is lower on the screen that the button was.

Comment: Yep, needs some css adjustment as well. I agree that replacing the HTML content is the best solution.